Probability of rolling every possible digit from a die after given number of attempts
A 26-sided die is rolled 39 times. What is the probability of each possible roll occurring at least once? I originally had phrased the problem in terms of cards from a purchased box but turned it into an equivalent problem in terms of dice for clarity.
This is my attempt.

All possibilities are equally likely, so one can divide the number of possibilities that result in at least one of each digit by the total number of possibilities.
The total number of possibilities is $26^{39}$.
I am struggling to find a way to determine the number of ways that each number can be rolled at least once.


This doesn't say anything about probability, so we can't determine the odds. Can you be more specific? For example, "rare" doesn't mean anything.

Can you edit for clarity?  What does "rare" mean here?  Are there other cards that are not rare?  Are these $39$ drawn from a larger pool?  If so, what are the characteristics of that pool?  If not, well...how are those $39$ cards selected?

Your method overcounts the possible decks. If we have two types of cards and deck size three, the deck "AAB" would be counted by choosing positions 1 and 3 for the unique rares and also by choosing positions 2 and 3.

I think you're counting the number of onto functions from a $39$-element set to a $26$-element set. That's given by the Stirling numbers, for which see https://oeis.org/A019538

@lulu the cards are drawn from a larger pool of rare cards. There are also non-rare cards, but they are not relevant to the discussion because the number of rare cards is fixed at 39.

@ThomasAndrews The cards come from buying a box of cards from the one-piece card game. They always have 39 rares in them (they also have other "common" cards but those shouldn't matter). There are 26 different "rare" cards that the 39 cards are chosen from. I changed the problem to a die problem because it is mathematically equivalent and clearer.

If I should change back to cards for other viewers that might not see the equivalence, let me know and I can make the explanation clearer.

@GerryMyerson. The Stirling number divided by 26^39 is exactly the number I am looking for. If you make this an answer, I will accept it.

This is not equivalent to the original question concerning rare cards in a box of booster packs, because the rare cards in a box are not independently random. The process of printing and packaging the cards practically guarantees that a box will contain at least one of each rare.

Another equivalent formulation: we have 26 urns, we place 39 balls inside them at random. What is the probabilty that all are not empty?

This is closely related to the coupon collector's problem. As Gerry says in the comments, the exact probability is the number of surjective functions from a $39$-element set to a $26$-element set divided by $26^{39}$, which is
$$\frac{26! S(39, 26)}{26^{39}} = \boxed{ \sum_{i=0}^{26} (-1)^{26-i} {26 \choose i} \left( \frac{i}{26} \right)^{39} }$$
where $S(39, 26)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind and the above identity can be deduced using inclusion-exclusion.
It's a little hard to tell from this expression exactly how big this probability actually is; right now it's not even clear if it's greater than or less than $\frac{1}{2}$. So the value of having this exact probability is unclear. Here is an approximation whose behavior is much easier to understand.
I will generalize to rolling a $k$-sided die $n$ times. For any given side of the die, what is the probability that we roll it at least once? It's $1$ minus the probability that we never roll it, which is $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{k} \right)^n$, so it's $1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{k} \right)^n$. Our first approximation is that when $k, n$ are both reasonably large but also similar in size we have $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{k} \right)^n  \approx e^{-\frac{n}{k}}$.
Our second approximation is that when $k, n$ are both reasonably large but also similar in size, these events (of rolling each side of the die at least once) are approximately independent. If you believe that this is a reasonable approximation, then the probability that we roll every side of the die at least once is approximately
$$\boxed{ \left( 1 - e^{-\frac{n}{k}} \right)^k }.$$
Plugging in $n = 39, k = 26$ gives
$$\left( 1 - e^{-\frac{39}{26}} \right)^{26} \approx 0.00141 \dots$$
so according to this approximation the probability is about $0.141 \dots \%$, although we haven't yet proven anything about how accurate this approximation is. But WolframAlpha knows how to calculate Stirling numbers, and it will tell you that the exact probability is actually $\boxed{ 0.156 \dots \% }$. So we didn't do so bad!
We can also see a rough approximate version of the solution to the coupon collector's problem in this expression by asking: how big does $n$ have to get for this probability to become reasonably large, say at least $\frac{1}{e}$? Using the exponential approximation $\left( 1 - \frac{x}{m} \right)^m \approx e^{-x}$ like before we see that this happens when $e^{-\frac{n}{k}} \approx \frac{1}{k}$, or $n \approx k \log k$, which is what the solution to the coupon collector's problem would predict. Here we have $26 \log 26 \approx 84.7$ so $39$ rolls is a little under half the number we need for a decent shot.

Exact values of the Stirling numbers are tabulated at the oeis link I gave in my comment.

@Gerry: sure, but are they all that useful? Can you tell from the exact formula for the Stirling numbers that the probability is an increasing function of $n$, for example? In the approximation it's much clearer.

I'm not talking about a formula. I'm talking about the exact numbers, the integers $k!S(n,k)$. https://oeis.org/A019538/b019538.txt

@Gerry: sure, but again, are they all that useful? Can you tell from that table that the probability is an increasing function of $n$?

You can tell from common sense that the probability is an increasing function of $n$. Surely the larger the domain (for a fixed size of the codomain), the greater the probability of an onto function.

For a much tigther (but perhaps less useful in practice) approximation see here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162764/understanding-a-particular-approximation-for-stirlings-number-of-the-second-kin/163085#163085
